# How to Animate object in android while

Tags: android, android-animation, transparent

Is there a way to for a Bitmap object to have a transparent background instead of solid color.. I'd like my background image (set on XML layout to show)?

sadly, none of the other question worked for me, otherwise, I wouldn't be asking... THANKS IN ADVANCE! ALSO, any tips on how to get the animation to work with XML?

```
import android.content.Context;  
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

public class Vehicle extends View{

Bitmap vehicle;
int x_axisMovement;

public Vehicle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    vehicle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.vehicle_bus);

    x_axisMovement = 1024;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // NOT WORKING

    canvas.drawBitmap(vehicle, x_axisMovement, 400, null);

    if(x_axisMovement > -256){
        x_axisMovement -= 4;
    }
    else
    {
        x_axisMovement = 1024;
    }
    invalidate();
}

}
```

Comment: Post an image of current result you have

Comment: here [link]http://i.imgur.com/71MyozW.png the background isnt suppose to be black... it should be an image of a 2D road.

Comment: Are you using this in xml or programatically, if in xml post the xml where youusedit

Comment: sorry i wasnt clear... i used it programmatically as stated on my code above. the thing is... I WOULD LOVE to use the XML way but i have no idea how to do it... any advice on that too?

Comment: Make sure the black background is no the background of the app, parent view or of the view itself. It is not necessary to draw a transparent color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it in xml and add it in a relative layout so youll have a view on top of another view

**sample:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

    <com.example.Vehicle
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now `com.example` is the folder inside your `src` folder but you `might have different folder` just press `ctrl+shift+o` so it will automatically give you an hint to the class location.

Now your class

```
public class Vehicle extends View {

Bitmap vehicle;
int x_axisMovement;

public Vehicle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public Vehicle(Context context, AttributeSet s) {
    super(context, s);
    init();
}

public Vehicle(Context context, AttributeSet s, int style) {
    super(context, s, style);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    vehicle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    x_axisMovement = 1024;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // NOT WORKING

    canvas.drawBitmap(vehicle, x_axisMovement, 400, null);

    if (x_axisMovement > -256) {
        x_axisMovement -= 4;
    } else {
        x_axisMovement = 1024;
    }
    invalidate();
}
```

}

You need to have that 3 constructor to enable the class to be used in an xml form.

now the **result**:

[image]

The background is the big `ic_launcher` and the image from your class in the small `ic_launcher`.

Comment: thanks for the input! for some odd reason the code you assisted me with was unable to solve my problem (SEEMINGLY) which led me to some head-scratching marathon... So I went ahead & search of bugs in my code & found a bug... i seem to have duplicated the `setContentView()` and put the Vehicle object inside which nullifies my activity_layout... WHICH led to your provided code to work properly.. YEAY! on the sidenote: about the XML... it seem I have to programmatically embed the object since I wanted the image to "spawn" outside the layout & it seems like XML is unable to do it. THANK YOU :-)

Comment: I was able to programmically put it in by making a `FrameLayout` and cast the id then I frameLayout.addView(vehicle).